# Regular Expression look behind (not immediatly)

Tags: regex

Is it possible to write a lookbehind that checks for something not immediatly before the searched pattern?

Currently my Regular Expression looks like this:

```
(<p>)?\${placeholder}(</p>)?\n?
```

Goals: get rid of the `${placeholder}` and if it is the only element within a html paragraph, also remove the start and end tags.

Test string one, the `</p>` should not be stripped (doesn't work):

`<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: ${placeholder}</p>`

Test string two, the `<p>` and `</p>` should not be stripped (works):

`<p>${placeholder}</p>`

I was playing around by adding `(?<=<p>)` in front of the `</p>` with the effect that string one works, but no longer string two. As far as i understand this would only work for `<p></p>`.

Comment: How about using a [`<p>\${placeholder}</p>\n?|(<p>[^<]*)\${placeholder}([^<]*</p>)` regex and `\1\2` replacement](https://regex101.com/r/fB6zW6/1)?

Comment: that is actually not a bad idea. I was doing something similar for the moment, but with two sequential replace calls.

Comment: @stribizhev it solves my problem, but doesn't answer my question. I'm curious if a look behind would be possible after all.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, a lookbehind checks whether the text is preceded immediately by what's inside the lookbehind, and that's it. Maybe you should check for (?<=

${placeholder}) then, if I understood you correctly